# What does the kernel boot parameter "set acpi_osi=Linux" do?

Tags: kernel, graphics, laptop, acpi

I am facing an issue with brightness control in my laptop which has Intel HD graphics and Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit. So when I searched for a fix  I found that a common suggestion is to edit the GRUB file line, `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Documentation for boot parameter `acpi_osi` tells:

> ```
> acpi_osi=   [HW,ACPI] Modify list of supported OS interface strings
>             acpi_osi="string1"      # add string1 -- only one string
>             acpi_osi="!string2"     # remove built-in string2
>             acpi_osi=               # disable all strings
> ```
>
> — http://redsymbol.net/linux_boot_parameters/

I don't find a reason why this should **fix** any laptop issue.

So could anyone tell me what the kernel boot option `acpi_osi=Linux` do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> I think you mean `=Windows`, not `Linux`.
> The argument tells the kernel to lie
> to the ACPI BIOS and tell it that it
> is something *other* than Linux (which
> is why specifying Linux is silly).

I'm sure he means what he wrote. Yes, BIOS's usually disable functionality if Windows is not detected, but specifying Linux is not silly because by default the kernel responds false when asked if Linux is running. `acpi_osi=Linux` tells the kernel to respond true.(see `drivers/acpi/osl.c`) It seems that you need to tell the BIOS the truth.

It's either a driver problem or incorrect ACPI implementation. You'd have to take out your `dsdt` and disassemble it to review the code and get a better understanding of what is broke or disabled under the Linux OSI.

Reference

- [Why Linux ACPI driver pretends to be Windows and disables OSI(Linux) by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BIOSandUbuntu#DSDT_handling_Operating_System_Variants)
- [ACPI/Fix common problems - Gentoo Linux Wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20110320225941/http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/ACPI/Fix_common_problems)
- [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-boot-parameter)

Comment: this was very useful for my ubuntu 14.04 installation on my dell vostro 3750 with nvidia GeForce GT 525M, and Intel HD graphics.

Answer (score 20):

The parameter adds "Linux" to the list of supported operating systems that the kernel will get when it asks the BIOS "Hey, what do you support".  By adding that string, later, things that use ACPI will say "hey, I have a feature that needs ACPI, and I'm running Linux - what platforms are supported?" and they'll get back a list which will include Linux.

By setting this to Linux, you basically disable any checking to see if the BIOS says that certain ACPI features will work with certain operating systems.  And that often makes things works which were previously hidden.  But it could also break stuff that used to work, in [hopefully] rare cases. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean `=Windows`, not `Linux`.  The argument tells the kernel to lie to the ACPI BIOS and tell it that it is something *other* than Linux (which is why specifying Linux is silly).  Certain BIOS are known to check to see if they are being run under Windows, or a specific version of Windows, and disable functionality if they are not.  This parameter lets you work around that idiocy.

Comment: It says =Linux only.                 http://livinginjava.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-1010-brightness-problem-in-acer.html

Comment: Here is another link ,which says the same fix for fan issues...http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1398596   I feel this is considered to be a fix for several such issues..http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=56323