# Intel Graphic 3rd with 12.4 "nomodeset" working but?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel-graphics, suspend, brightness

If i'm booting with "nomodeset" then can't change Brightness/Login/Logout/Suspend/Resume ..etc. Accidentally booted once without "nomodeset" everything was working (Brightness/Login/Logout/Suspend/Resume).

I tried alot of fixes like "acpi_backlight=vendor" in kernel option, but without any success :-(

My system:
Ubuntu 12.4.3 (64bit)
On HP 250 (preinstalled with ubuntu)

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: **Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor      Graphics Controller** [8086:0166] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1854]
Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1854]
Kernel driver in use: mei
```

Best

Comment: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/3cp-hd4000gfx may have more useful drivers for you.

Comment: Their is no available Driver for my card and this Ubuntu Version.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use the `nomodeset` option? The intel VGA-s should be used with KMS enabled, so you shouldn't use the `nomodeset` option.

(Also unrelated to your question, but the `mei` module is known to cause problems, so if you don't need it you may want to blacklist it.)

*UPDATE:*

So you said in the comments that booting with KMS enabled results in a blank screen, but if you close/open the laptop lid everything gets normal. Maybe you have the problem stated [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Blank_screen_during_boot.2C_when_.22Loading_modules.22). You might try the solutions presented there.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1080644) is another similar problem which says that it is a problem that the blacklight is off. It links to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864513&p=11578848#post11578848) workaround. You may try that one also.

Or try the boot parameters presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/28848/221281). (add the acpi_osi=Linux parameter also, not just the acpi_backlight)

Comment: Because without "nomodeset" the boot is Blank. It's possible to boot the intel-VGA without nomodeset?

Comment: @Sia I do not understand. You wrote in your question that *Accidentally booted once without "nomodeset" everything was working*. Now you say that without nomodeset your PC won't even boot? So is it working without nomodeset, or not? The intel-VGA should be used without nomodeset. e.g look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics): *KMS is supported by Intel chipsets that use the i915 DRM driver and is enabled by default as of kernel v2.6.32.*

Comment: Yes the Booting got blank screen, closed the laptop for few seconds and again was working.
Tried again with the same tricks but ... ;-)

Comment: @Sia I updated my answer. You problem is likely not with KMS, but with something else. I presented some possible solutions.

Comment: her is the **/etc/default/grub**

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6670024/

Comment: @Sia Please try the solutions I linked in my answer. I think you should go backwards on those links I gave, because I think arch wiki solution won't work for you, but the last 2 one will likely help.

Comment: Thnx @falconer, before asking her, ive tried all of them, i can even hear the login sound, but the screen is totally blank.

Comment: @Sia OK. I will look into this next year. :) But I hope someone solves this for you sooner.

Comment: Thnx and happy new year, even i believe nobody can fix it. I 'll try to install other distro which is more stable & carefully made.

Regards