# Sony VAIO VPCEB1Z1E Ubuntu 13.10 Fan control

Tags: ati, sony

I'm searching for a way, to manage the laptops fan speed. It seems that it constantly runs at the same speed, so when I try for example playing games that put some stress on my computer, I can see graphic artifacts.

I've seen this link [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) and tried to install things how I'm supposed to, but unfortunately, my laptop doesn't have any "pwm-capable sensor modules installed".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my laptop. Its fan went on/off for seemingly no reason (temp cca. 40 Celsius). The following grub update did the trick to me:

In terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

and after this line add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"'
```

It works like a charm for me.

Comment: I've tried doing what you suggested. But that didn't solve my problem. The fan for me isn't going on/off. It's just always on on very low RPM, even when the CPU is under stress. Maybe having the 12.04 LTS version would solve the problem. The latest one doesn't seem to have all of the good stuff working.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't get your question fully. I'd still recommend to play around `acpi` options in grub. Find some reasoning [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do).