# Disable Fn-keys brightness change on Dell Inspiron E1405

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell, laptop, brightness

I've got an old Dell E1405 which smoothly runs 14.04, with one caveat that is.

When I press the Fn button with arrow-up or arrow-down, the brightness jumps in huge steps.

Is there a way to disable this? So that the brightness is only adjusted by the hardware (I would believe that the BIOS adjusts it because prior to system startup, I can also change brightness)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It may help to set `acpi` OS and vendor in the bootloader by [editing grub.cfg](http://askubuntu.com/a/19487/178596), as mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do): (by adding the lines `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor`) - this I find works on a few machines to get brightness to be less jumpy.

Comment: Thank you Wilf, you're golden. This has worked perfectly. Hope someone else can use this information too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to set acpi OS and vendor in the bootloader by [editing grub.cfg](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/178596), as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do), by adding this:

```
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
```

To the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`. You then need to run `sudo update-grub` and reboot to make the changes.

This I find works on a few machines, to get brightness to be less jumpy etc