# My laptop (Acer E15-511-P7UX) stopped responding in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intel-graphics, microcode

My laptop is freezing and nothing works when it freezes! And after 4 seconds the laptop's fan rotates at max speed at 2-second intervals. I had to hold the power button to force shutdown but I am losing all the important work I was doing.

I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1-7</kbd> but nothing happens. I searched Google and many people have the problem but none have the solution. A YouTube comment said in `etc/default/grub`, change `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=linux"` but that didn't work.

The proprietary drivers are Intel according to additional drivers. I did a clean install of Ubuntu, not with dual-boot or VirtualBox.

And I cleaned my laptop even though there is no dust. I also clean-installed and the solution I got from the YouTube comment made it worse, so I reinstalled Ubuntu. I also tried laptop mode tools.

Even the shutdown command restarts the laptop.

And when I check anything in the additional drivers and refresh/reload to download them, it says no internet connection but I am connected to a 4mbps network.

Maybe because it's opensource and there are so many varieties of PC laptops and mine is notebook.

Even if I wanted to, I can't go back to Windows 10 because it's not free anymore.

Comment: Do you get different results when it's on battery power than you get when it's plugged in to AC power?

Comment: When on battery it hangs after 1 or 2 hours

Comment: When plugged in...hangs when it gets suspended automatically....but not always

Comment: Is there any command to check for and fix errors in ubuntu?

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your question as comments get deleted for any number of reasons.

Comment: In windows it was sfc scan now ...or something

Comment: All due respect, but you are assuming that this is a software problem.  (Unlikely IMHO) As others have stated this sounds much more like an overheat problem than anything else.

Comment: Not overheat....because there is no heat....and it was fine in windows 10. I changed to ubuntu because of screen of death

Comment: Please [edit] new information into your question as comments get deleted for any number of reasons.  "Fine under Windows 10" (Screen of Death does not sound fine) No heat? Impossible.

Answer (score 1):

How old is the laptop? Have you ever cleaned it? People tend to forget that dust does enter inside laptops. I think that, before posting any software-relate question here, you should run an errand to the service and ask for a general check for your device. It may need undusting, fans may need to be oiled. Only after eliminating any hardware-related suspicions, you can look elsewhere for your solution.

Also, check on Acer Forum. It may help you: [community.acer.com/t5/Discussion-Forums/ct-p/boards](http://How%20old%20is%20the%20laptop?%20Have%20you%20ever%20cleaned%20it?%20People%20tend%20to%20forget%20that%20dust%20does%20enter%20inside%20laptops.%20I%20think%20that,%20before%20posting%20any%20software-relate%20question%20here,%20you%20should%20run%20an%20errand%20to%20the%20service%20and%20ask%20for%20a%20general%20check%20for%20your%20device.%20It%20may%20need%20undusting,%20fans%20may%20need%20to%20be%20oiled.%20Only%20after%20eliminating%20any%20hardware-related%20suspicions,%20you%20can%20look%20elsewhere%20for%20your%20solution.%20Also,%20check%20on%20Acer%20Forum.%20It%20may%20help%20you:%20community.acer.com/t5/Discussion-Forums/ct-p/boards)

(I've decided to move my comment on the "Answers" section, as it is more adequate here.)

Comment: It is 6 monts old laptop 2 gb ram

Comment: I will clean it right away and see....should i reinstall ubuntu again

Comment: @Ghostumour Do you intend to clean it yourself? Well, in that case, please, don't forget the fans. The may need to be oiled. Just a small drop on the tip of a needle. Of course, you know that it's not the kind of oil you use to fry potatoes, because you'll... "fry" your fans.  As for reinstalling Ubuntu, let's see first how your laptop behaves after the "lifting".

Comment: He he i am not planning to boil eggs on my laptop :) and potatoe fries :)

Comment: I will clean it first thing in the morning

Comment: @Ghostumour :-) Good! You need a special high quality oil that doesn't dry. The kind of oil that it's used for delicate mechanisms.

Comment: I found this in the youtube,,,can you check its valid...1. Navigate to [File System > etc > default > grub] 2. Change the following lines to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=\"Linux\"" 3. Then open a terminal, and type:  sudo update-grub Push Enter. 4. Reboot. Works for me on all affected laptops. This solution has been around for years, but for whatever reason has not proliferated widely through the community

Comment: and this too..On my Dell Inspiron 15R 5520, the following solution worked for me: 1) In the terminal, run "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub" (no quotes) 2) Edit the line of the file that reads, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"   so that it reads   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"    (with quotes) and then save the file. 3) From the terminal, run   sudo update-grub 4) Shutdown your computer and then turn it back on (cold boot). My computer's fans would spin at their highest speed as well, but editing the above file brought them under control.

Comment: OH mu god! I posted a long comment.

Comment: I cleaned it...but there is no dust in it....i even oiled the fan with one big drop....its the same.....I am going to try the above mentioned solution, Hope it works.

Comment: Here's a post related to acpi_osi kernel boot parameter that you may find informative: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your laptop's cooling system. It seems that it is not able to cool the processor when CPU usage is high. It might be due to dust settled inside for a long period of time. I would advice you to use a lighter desktop environment such as lxde as a temporary solution. Cleaning the laptop from inside would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved finally!!
Thankyou for this community....I finally found it :)

And sorry ...My level is low...so I can't post any potato...Think this as a potato *O*

Here is the Solution:

-When you boot the live system, move your selection to 'Try Elementary OS without installing', then press 'E' on your keyboard (for editing the boot options).
Move the cursor to the line where it says "Linux ....... splash screen" at the end of the line insert a space and then write 'modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core'.
Hit F10 for booting. Now install Elementary OS and reboot.

-Turn on your notebook and do all the updates (sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade).
Next open a terminal and write 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub', go to the line where it says 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"' and change it to 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=dw_dmac,dw_dmac_core"'. On your keyboard press 'Control + X', then 'Y' and 'Enter' to save and exit. Now write 'sudo update-grub' in the terminal.

Reboot and you should be done!

If you're interested in what you have changed on your computer read this:
http://www.differencebetween.net/tec...n-dma-and-pio/

No.....this didn't work either

Maybe if i change to an older kernel...it may work....any suggestions about stable kernel?...guys

Changed to a random kernel....it finally is working smoothly.......pwew!!

Comment: I am glad you found a solution to your problem but there are a couple of issues in your answer that I would like you to clarify. 1. The link you provided doesn't exist; 2. What is this "random" kernel that worked for you? Can you please specify its version? 3. Please describe how you installed a different kernel so this answer is more useful for users who don't know how to.

Comment: I installed linux mint, then I still got the same error. Then, in software updater in linux mint...there is an option to easily install kernels and delete previous kernels.  The current version was 4.4.3 i downgraded to 4.4.1(did not work) and then 4.4.2 and it worked.