# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 freezes at shutdown

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, 18.04, shutdown, asus

I have bought a new desktop; it's an Asus VivoBook Pro N552VW. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot with Windows 10. The system is working perfectly but **it freezes during shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate**. It also freezes in a singular situation: I succesfully login when I write the correct password on the first try, but if I fail at least one time, then when I write it correctly, **it freezes as stated above**.

These are PC's detailed:

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7 6700HQ Processor
- OS: Windows 10 Home
- Chipset: Intel® HM170 Chipset
- Memory: DDR4 2133 MHz SDRAM, 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up to 16 GB SDRAM
- Graphics: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M with 2G/4G GDDR5 VRAM
- Storage: 2.5" 9.5mm SATA3; 1TB HDD 5400 RPM; 1TB HDD 7200 RPM; PCIE x 4 256G / 512G

.

.

The system is fully updated using Update Manager.

- How can I determine what is causing the freeze?
- How can I fix this?

.

.

Initally, Ubuntu didn't power on, but adding **acpi=off** I could fix it. This rather didn't help me to resolve the shutdown.

I tried these things:

- I tried adding Intel microcodes, but it didn't help.
- I added quiet splash in GRUB-edit.
- I did a lot of changes in GRUB-edit, but nothing brought me a successfully resolution.

After all these attempts, when I powered off my laptop, the typical written that came up was: `Wlp2s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)` and `reboot: System halted`.

Then, yesterday I added `nomodeset` in front of `quiet splash` in GRUB-edit, and Ubuntu stucked no more when the writtens stated above came up, but one step ahead: it stucked at Ubuntu log.

Has somebody ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is, try another distro.....
Meant to be more helpful than not. Truly, some distros and versions of the kernel/ GUIS work different on different machines ime

Comment: I'n actually thinking that, if nobody can give me an answer, I'll try an other distro. Anyway thank you so much for interest!!!

Comment: I'd try Linux Mint, if I were you. It's basically Ubuntu, but they tweak it to their preferences. If that doesn't work, try an earlier release of Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I'll wait some day for a miracle ahahah, then I'll do it.

Comment: Stick with Debian or Debian based distros for netflix support!

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 16.04.4 and it works! I think there is something doesn't work in the last version with my laptop.
Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tried an older version: Ubuntu 16.04.4, and it works fine.
I think they haven't fixed every bugs with every computers yet.

Thanks to **https://askubuntu.com/users/36140/robert-sederholm**!

Thanks also to **jeydee**, who kindly answered me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1756226/comments/20

Using Asus ROG GL752-VW, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M. Also currently using nvidia-driver-390 instead of Nouveau. Running dual booted Win10 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had some ACPI related issues on Lenovo IdeaPad 330 running Ubuntu 18.04.1. Passing `acpi=off` fixed some of them (WLAN card detection, freezes on logout, and most random freezes), but it broke some other things instead: Ubuntu froze on reboots/shutdowns, touchpad didn't work, battery not detected, and also after installing nvidia CUDA drivers `nvidia-msi` was failing to communicate with `/dev/nvidia0` reporting ACPI related errors in `dmesg`. What worked for me was replacing `acpi=off` kernel boot option with `acpi_osi=Linux` (and I also noticed `nomodeset` the OP mentioned broke some things too). You can read about `acpi_osi=Linux` option in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/50776/392634).